# Transition css animation works only once

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, react-hooks, transition

I have a problem with css animation in react app triggering by useState. Animation between width changes works only once on one component. (I have array of tags on upper level)

```
...

const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isMounted);
    setIsMounted(true);
    // setIsMounted(false);
    return () => {
      console.log('There is');
      setIsMounted(false);
    }
  }, []);

...

<div
    id={item.label}
    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}      
    className={isMounted ? 'i-tag' : 'no-tag' }
    > {`some text`}
</div>
```

and scss here

```
.i-tag {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: max-content;
  transition: width 1s ease-in;
}

.no-tag { 
  @extend .i-tag;
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you create a sandbox version reproducing the issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-hypatia-p3s92?file=/src/App.js   here it is ,its stange here animations work on all items but i dont why element appears at start and it doesnt matter that width is 0 and overflow hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TransitionGroup` with `CSSTransition` for animating array of components.

Actually there are 2 ways to achieve animation of array of components in React,

1. By your own code which is bit trickier to do it perfectly
2. use some packages like 'react-transition-group' which is much easier to integrate

If you would like to use the package 'react-transition-group', here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-ives-x2kyt) on how to use it

```
<TransitionGroup component="ul">
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <CSSTransition key={todo} timeout={700} classNames="item">
          <li>
            {todo}{" "}
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setTodos(todos.filter((t) => t !== todo));
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </li>
        </CSSTransition>
      ))}
    </TransitionGroup>
```

Courtesy: https://typeofnan.dev/how-to-animate-items-out-of-an-array-in-react/